# MySQL transactions in a stored procedure

Tags: mysql, isolation-level, database-deadlocks

I have a stored procedure which collects data from several sources, transforms and in the end deletes and then dumps the data in `TableA`
While this stored procedure is running, other users often perform a select query on `TableA` resulting in a deadlock, causing the stored procedure to fail.

My stored procedure does use `SET TRANSACTION  ISOLATION  LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;` at the beginning however it does not seem to work or I am using it wrongly.

Without using `READ/WRITE LOCKS` is there a way I can ensure that this does not happen?

MySQL version: 5.7.23-enterprise-commercial-advanced-log

Comment: Lock the table accordingly immediately before the operation which may fall in deadlock, and unlock it immediately after. Or increase transaction level - maybe even until serializable.

Comment: @Akina can you elaborate on the "increase transaction level" part.

Answer (score 2):

I have a number of comments:

- I assume you're using `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` because without the optional locking clause, SELECT does not acquire row locks, so should not cause a deadlock.
- Other read queries without the `FOR UPDATE` clause don't need row locks. They cannot be contributing to the deadlocks.
- To prevent deadlocks, you need to use an atomic lock. Consider [LOCK TABLES](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/lock-tables.html).
- Changing the isolation level has no effect on the currently running transaction. If you already have a transaction in progress, you cannot change its isolation level on the fly. The change to the isolation level only applies to transactions you begin subsequently.
- The `READ UNCOMMITTED` isolation level does not eliminate the need for queries to acquire locks, if they need locks in other isolation levels.
- In 20+ years of using MySQL, I've never found a legitimate use for `READ UNCOMMITTED`. I avoid it.

Comment: Simple `SELECT` is causing this issue.
`LOCK TABLE WRITE` does seem to solve this issue, however that is my last resort.

I am still unsure why `TRANSACTION` is not working as it is supposed to, and want to figure out the correct usage here(if that exists).

Regarding your 4th point, just to be clear, the SELECT which is causing the deadlock is running in a different session.